# Can't Access JS Regex Result - Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some code where I'm scraping URLs from a page and then using a regex to get the text between two strings. When I do that, I get the match that I want but I can't access the result.

```
evaluated.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element.match(/.com\/(.*?)\?fref/)[1]);
}, this);
```

If I remove the `[1]`, I see the results in the console as:

```
[
    '.com/jkahan?fref',
    'jkahan',
    index: 20,
    input: 'https://www.example.com/jkahan?fref=pb&hc_location=friends_tab' 
]
```

But when I add the `[1]` to access the result I want, I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have this done for all the elements in the array `evaluated`. My guess is that one of those element doesn't match and it throws the error because, in that case, `match` will return `null`.

It's better to store the result of `match` in a variable first. That way, you can check if it's `null` or not before accessing `[1]` of it:

```
evaluated.forEach(function(element) {
    var result = element.match(/.com\/(.*?)\?fref/);  // store the result of 'match' in the variable 'result'
    if(result)                                        // if there is a result (if 'result' is not 'null')
        console.log(result[1]);                       // then you can access it's [1] element
}, this);
```

Comment: That's weird. I tried something like that before using that same if statement. I must have messed it up somehow. That worked. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! You probably forgot to remove the `[1]` from the line before `if`.